# Determine if a public key point y is negative or positive, odd or even?

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, keys

Take an elliptic curve cryptography public key (x, y) and its additive inverse (x, -y). How do you identify which is the positive point and which is the negative point?

Examples:

Private key 1 -> (x, y)

```
x = 0x79be667ef9dcbbac55a06295ce870b07029bfcdb2dce28d959f2815b16f81798L

y = 0x483ada7726a3c4655da4fbfc0e1108a8fd17b448a68554199c47d08ffb10d4b8L

-y = 0xb7c52588d95c3b9aa25b0403f1eef75702e84bb7597aabe663b82f6f04ef2777L
```

Private key 2 -> (x, y)

```
x = 0xc6047f9441ed7d6d3045406e95c07cd85c778e4b8cef3ca7abac09b95c709ee5L

y = 0x1ae168fea63dc339a3c58419466ceaeef7f632653266d0e1236431a950cfe52aL

-y = 0xe51e970159c23cc65c3a7be6b99315110809cd9acd992f1edc9bce55af301705L
```

Private key 3 -> (x, y)

```
x = 0xf9308a019258c31049344f85f89d5229b531c845836f99b08601f113bce036f9L

y = 0x388f7b0f632de8140fe337e62a37f3566500a99934c2231b6cb9fd7584b8e672L

-y = 0xc77084f09cd217ebf01cc819d5c80ca99aff5666cb3ddce4934602897b4715bdL
```

---

Also, how can you identify which public key is odd and which is even?

For example: private key 1 x,y is odd, private key 2 x,y is even (based with pub key).

---

Comment: Unlike the ordinary integers, there's no notion of "positive" or "negative" points on an elliptic curve. So asking which of (x,y) and (x,-y) is the negative point is not relevant. The same for even and odd.

Comment: http://remon78eg.tk/curve/ this site shows you that any point on the curve can still hold the private key information and you can extract odd/even , mod 2 or mod 3 from the public key, try it yourself also see the video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iux7to1iNlw

Comment: @remon78eg (Moderator note). The above comment originally was an answer, but it did not address the question, hence the removal. Independently, the linked material apparently requires a _variation_ of a standard curve, e.g. secp256k1. The goal could be extraction of private key information from an implementation (e.g. BC wallet) modified without detailed code analysis, merely by changing secp256k1 parameters. That's nice, but the need to change curve parameters warrants at least a note along the links.

Answer (score 9):

Elements of finite fields don't really have a sign. But depending on context you can define a property that's different for $x$ and $-x$ (when $x$ is not $0$) and call that property *sign*.

Some possible choices:

- A number is called a *square* (or [Quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue)) if there is another number which produces it when squared. Since positive real numbers are squares, identifying square field elements with a positive sign is a natural choice.

  The [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) is 0 for 0, +1 for squares and -1 for non-squares. The Legendre symbol of the product of two numbers is the product of the two Legendre symbols, which mirrors how signs behave under multiplication.

  You can even define $i = \sqrt{-1}$ to get some kind of complex numbers. Imaginary values of the $y$ coordinate of an elliptic curve correspond to its twist.
- You can use the least significant bit. Computing this is very cheap, you only need to look at that one bit. This approach is often used to store the "sign" of a compressed elliptic curve coordinate.
- Values smaller than $p/2$ have one sign, values greater than $p/2$ the other. I believe Bitcoin uses this convention to define canonical signatures.

You can extend any of these definitions from the underlying field to the elliptic curve defined over that field by defining the sign of the point as the sign of its $y$ coordinate.

Comment: Bitcoin does use $s<n/2$ signatures, but r,s in an ECDSA signature are not a point or even elements of $F_p$ like point coordinates, they are nonzero elements of $Z_n^+$ _one_ of which, r, is derived from an x-coordinate.

Comment: It's worth noting that the choice may depend on representation of the field elements. Most of the time, prime field elements are represented as non-negative integers from 0 to $p-1$, but one may use an alternate representation like: integers from $-(p-1)/2$ to $(p-1)/2$. With such representations, there is a natural choice for what we could call the "sign" of the element, and perhaps even a limited definition of "ordering" between elements

Answer (score 1):

In finite fields there is no distinction between positive and negative numbers. This implies that you also do not have positive or negative points in an elliptic curve over a finite field.  But you can nevertheless distinguish the two points by looking at the least significant bit.
For instance, this will be used by the point compression method.

Comment: why does the LSB distinguish the two points? how come they can't have the same LSB?

Comment: @MatthewTranmer Assume a prime order field where we choose the representation $0 \le x < p$. Then $-x$ is represented as $p-x$. Since $p$ is odd, this changes parity and thus the least significant bit. (Except when $x=0$ of course)